# internal distribution of BlackBerry Application

Tags: blackberry

I would like to know if there is a way to distribute a BlackBerry application internally within a company without having to put it in the Black Berry App World?

I know that for iOS devices there is the iOS Enterprise license and for Android deices we can distribute the application internaly by sending the .apk file. But what about the BlackBerry?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For BlackBerry smartphones, you can package your app into a .jad file and put it on a webserver somewhere that the phone's webbrowser can reach. Or you can use the Blackberry Desktop Software to install apps as well.

For BlackBerry Playbook, if you don't use Apple World, then the only way I know of is to package the app into a .bar file (in Playbook OS 2.0, Android .apk apps can be repackaged into .bar files) and "side-load" it using a third party installer named DDPB Installer.

Answer (score 0):

If your organization installs a BES server, you can deploy your cods to single users and to groups of users as well, and also set the permissions.

More info [here](http://us.blackberry.com/business/software/bes/).